# Login loop Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, login, lightdm, xserver

I'm reposting this from another question below (same issue):
I'm trying to log into my PC running 18.04 with *lightDM*, but whenever I attempt to sign in, the screen flashes black and returns to my *lightDM* greeter. If I switch to a different tty and run `startx`, gnome will start and appears to run fine.

I've tried reinstalling *lightdm**, which changed nothing.
Then I tried `gdm3`, which would freeze after clicking my user, saying

> authentication error

and then I tried reinstalling the *NVidia* drivers (affecting nothing), and I have been trying this on a few different users.

If I check `.xsession-errors`, these are the only lines that stand out:

> xrdb: Can't open display ''
>   xhost:  unable to open display ""
>   xhost:  unable to open display ""

It seems that X/gnome works fine, so I'm not exactly sure where the problem resides...